# Can function inside a class method inherit the class properties?

Tags: javascript, function, class, inheritance

Is it possible to make imported module `createTaskTabEl` to inherit `UI` class properties? I would like to avoid repetitive passing parameters inside the function.

```
import createTaskTabEl ...

class UI {
  constructor() {
    this.projectListUlEl = document.querySelector("ul.list-projects");
    this.projectTaskContainer = document.querySelector(".tasks");
    this.controller;
    this.task;
  }

...


  renderTasks() {
  ...
      let element = createTaskTabEl(task, this.controller);

      ...
    }
  }
}
//other file
export default function createTaskTabElement(task, controller) {
...
new CheckButton(task, this.element, controller),
        new EditButton(task, this.element, controller),
        new CloseButton(task, this.element, controller),
...
}  const tab = new TaskTabElement();
return tab; //returns dom element
```

I tried to remove `task, this.controller` parameters from `createTaskTabElement` call and log `this.controller` inside it but it returns undefined.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)